# Multiplicities and tangent cones of singular points on $x^3 + y^3 - 3x^2 - 3y^2 +3xy +1 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How does one find the multiplicities and tangent cones of the singular points of $x^3 + y^3 - 3x^2 - 3y^2 +3xy +1 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

I believe that the singular points are
$$ \left( \frac{3 - i \sqrt{3} }{2}, \frac{3+ i \sqrt{3}}{2} \right),
\left( \frac{3 + i \sqrt{3} }{2}, \frac{3- i \sqrt{3}}{2} \right), $$
but I'm not sure how to find the tangent cones and multiplicities.

Comment: Those points aren't on the curve.

Comment: $(x,y)=(1,1)$ is and there the equation is $(x-1)^3 + 3 (x-1) (y-1) + (y-1)^3=0$ which has  "tangent cone" $ (x-1) (y-1)=0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $x^3 + y^3 - 3x^2z - 3y^2z +3xyz +z^3=0$ in ${\Bbb P}^2$ which has the singular point $(x:y:z)=(1:1:1)$, in the affine $z=1$ this is $(x,y)=(1,1)$ where the equation is your equation, I just write it about the point, $(x-1)^3 + 3 (x-1) (y-1) + (y-1)^3=0$ from which the "tangent cone" $(x-1)(y-1)=0$ is apparent.

But the tangent cone can detect regular tangents at nonsingular points too: The line at infinity (for the affine where $z=1$) $z=0$ cuts the curve in $x^3+y^3=0$ or $(x:y:z)=(1:-1:0), (\frac{1\pm\sqrt3 i}2:1:0).$ Here the tangent lines are (checking in the affine $x=1:$ $(y,z)=(-1,0):$ $3\cdot((y+1)-3z)=0,$ and for $(y,z)=(\frac{1\pm\sqrt3 i}2,0):$  $\color{blue}{ \frac32 (-1 \pm i \sqrt3)}\cdot (y-\frac{1\pm\sqrt3 i}2)$ ). These lift back to $y+x-3z=0$ and $y-\frac{1\pm\sqrt3 i}2 x=0.$ And in the affine $x=1$ over the reals $y+x-3=0$ is an [asymptote](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/k7ef882p). Also note that the product of the other two tangents is $x^2-xy+y^2=0$ which you can see as the real point at the origin (the intersection point of the two complex "asymptotes").